# How to (re)fill circle in canvas - requestAnimationFrame - HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

how can I fill the "new" canvas circle that appears next to the older one.
There is no problem with rectangle for example:

** 
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+quadratto.r+','+quadratto.g+','+quadratto.b+',1)';

```
  quadratto.x += quadratto.speedX;
  quadratto.y += quadratto.speedY;
  quadratto.speedY += quadratto.speedY*(-0.15);
  ctx.fillRect(quadratto.x-quadratto.h/4, quadratto.y-quadratto.h/2, 2, 2);**
```

What I want to do?
I'm creating animation in canvas where random-sized-color circle will appear and 
 it will move in a specified direction. The new canvas layaer will appear in the next frame (fps) with a new(old) circle.

```js
var myCanvasPattern = document.createElement('canvas');
myCanvasPattern.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvasPattern.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(myCanvasPattern);
var ryC = myCanvasPattern.getContext('2d');

function lottery(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
}

var allQuadro = [];
var fps = 50;
var lastTime = 0;

animationLoop();
function animationLoop(time){
    requestAnimationFrame( animationLoop );
    if(time-lastTime>=1000/fps){
        lastTime = time;
    
        
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){ 
            allQuadro.push({
            r : lottery(0, 240),
            g : lottery(0, 240),
            b : lottery(0, 240),
            circleR : lottery(10, 30),
            x : myCanvasPattern.width/2,
            y : myCanvasPattern.height/2,
            speedX : lottery(-1000,1000)/100,
            speedY : lottery(-1000,1000)/100 
            })
            }
ryC.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
ryC.fill(0,0,myCanvasPattern.width, myCanvasPattern.height); 

    for(var i=0; i<allQuadro.length;i++){
        var circle = allQuadro[i];
        ryC.fillStyle  = 'rgba('+circle.r+','+circle.g+','+circle.b+',1)';
       
        circle.x += circle.speedX;
        circle.y += circle.speedY;
        //HERE's THE PROBLEM BELOW. HOW TO CREATE NEW ONE THAT APPEARS NEXT TO PREVIOUS ONE WITH NEW RANDOM COLOR
        ryC.arc(circle.x-circle.circleR/2, circle.y-circle.circleR/2, circleR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        //ryC.fill();
    }
    
    
//    ryC.fillStyle = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',1)';
//ryC.arc(x+speedX, y+speedY, circleR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
//ryC.fill();
}
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fillRect()` will fill directly to the canvas without going via a path (versus for example `rect()`).

The `arc()` on the other hand will add to a path which needs to be filled later. It also require the path to be cleared in-between the calls using `beginPath()`.

A simple way to think about it is to wrap the necessary code into a function that acts like `fillRect()`:

```
function fillArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();                 // clear current path
  ctx.arc.apply(ctx, arguments);   // apply arguments to arc() call
  ctx.fill();
  // notice that the arc still exist on the path after this call
  // so to "truly" behave like fillRect() you could consider an
  // additional beginPath() here.. it will depend on your code
}
```

In action:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#09f";
fillArc(70, 70, 70, 0, 6.28);

ctx.fillStyle = "#0a9";
fillArc(220, 70, 70, 0, 6.28);

function fillArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc.apply(ctx, arguments);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

If you are bold you can also add the method to the context itself before calling `getContext()`:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillArc = function() {
  this.beginPath();
  this.arc.apply(this, arguments);
  this.fill();
}
```

The use it like any other method:

```
ctx.fillArc( ... );
```

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillArc = function() {
  this.beginPath();
  this.arc.apply(this, arguments);
  this.fill();
}

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#09f";
ctx.fillArc(70, 70, 70, 0, 6.28);

ctx.fillStyle = "#0a9";
ctx.fillArc(220, 70, 70, 0, 6.28);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```